# How do I identify and resolve segmentation fault errors in C?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, segmentation-fault, early-stopping

After compiling and running "project1.exe", I received a SIGSEGV error using the debugger, and am unable to discover what is causing the issue. The debugger traced the issue back to the "combine_like_terms" method but I'm not sure what's causing it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated regarding any part of the project. I'm using cygwin to compile and run the program.

For background, I can only edit the printandcombine.c and printandcombine.h files:

printandcombine.h:

```
#ifndef PRINTANDCOMBINE_H
#define PRINTANDCOMBINE_H

//Returns a string representation of the struct term_t
char * term_to_string(term_t * term);

//Prints a linkedlist in no specific order
void print_linklist(node_t * curr);

//Returns a new linkedlist that is the result of combining the like terms
node_t * combine_like_terms(const node_t * current_node_ptr);

#endif
```

printandcombine.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "common.h"

/* Functions */

char * term_to_string(term_t * term)
{
    char *str = malloc((sizeof(char)) * 1024);
    
    sprintf(str, "%d%c%d ", term->coefficient, term->var,   term->exponent);
    printf("%s", str);

    free(str);

    return str;
}

void print_linklist(node_t * curr)
{
    printf("%s", term_to_string(curr->term));

    if (!(curr->next_node == NULL))
    {
        print_linklist(curr->next_node);
    }
}

node_t * combine_like_terms(const node_t * current_node_ptr)
{
    node_t *temp = (node_t *)current_node_ptr;

    node_t *out = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *move = out;

    int x = 0;

    while (!(temp == NULL))
    {
        if (temp->term->exponent > x)
        {
            x =temp->term->exponent;
        }
        temp = temp->next_node;
    }
    
    for (; x >= 0; x--)
    {
        temp = (node_t *)current_node_ptr;
        int a = 0;
        while (!(temp == NULL))
        {
            if (temp->term->exponent == x)
            {
                a = a + temp->term->coefficient;
            }
        
        move->term->coefficient = a;
        move->term->var = 'x';
        move->term->exponent = x;
        if (x > 0)
        {
        move->next_node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
        move = move->next_node;
        }
    }
            
}

return out;
}
```

project1.c:

```
/* This is your main file */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"common.h"
#include"buildlinklist.h"
#include"printandcombine.h"

int main() {
    node_t * node_ptr = NULL;
    node_t * new_node_ptr=NULL;

    printf("NAME: Name\n");
    
    /* Build linklist */
    read_objects(&node_ptr);

    
    /* Print the link list */
    printf("Original: ");
    print_linklist(node_ptr);
    
    /* Combine like terms in the link list and create a new link list */
    new_node_ptr=combine_like_terms(node_ptr);
    printf("\nCombined: : ");
    /* Print new combine linklist */
    print_linklist(new_node_ptr);

    printf("\nNAME: Name\n");
    free(node_ptr);
    free(new_node_ptr);
    return 0;


}
```

buildlist.h:

```
#ifndef BUILDLINKLIST_H
#define BUILDLINKLIST_H

#include"common.h"


/* Read from a text file and put in to a term_t structure. Then create a linklist of node (each node has an element of term struct.)*/
void read_objects(node_t ** pointer_to_node_ptr);

/* Assign value to term_t object elements */
term_t * term_from_string(char * buff);

/* Add a node to the link list */
int add_node(node_t ** pointer_to_node_ptr, void * term);

#endif
```

buildlist.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"common.h"



/* Assign value to term_t object elements */
term_t * term_from_string(char * buff) {
    term_t * ret = malloc(sizeof(term_t));
    ret->coefficient=atoi(strtok(buff, " "));
    ret->var=*strtok(NULL, " ");
    ret->exponent=atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    return ret;
}


/* Add a node to the link list */
int add_node(node_t ** pointer_to_node_ptr, void * term) {
  int ret = 0;
  node_t * newnode_ptr = (node_t *) malloc(sizeof(node_t));
  if (newnode_ptr == NULL) {
    ret = -1;
  }
  else {
    newnode_ptr->term = term;
    newnode_ptr->next_node = *pointer_to_node_ptr;
    *pointer_to_node_ptr = newnode_ptr;
  }
  return ret;
}


/* Read from a text file and put in to a term_t structure. Then create a linklist of node (each node has an element of term struct.)*/
void read_objects(node_t ** pointer_to_node_ptr) {

    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[BUFFERLEN];
    fp = fopen("terms.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(buffer, BUFFERLEN,fp)) {
        term_t * this_term;
        this_term =  term_from_string(buffer);
        add_node(pointer_to_node_ptr, this_term);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

common.h:

```
#ifndef COMMON_H
#define COMMON_H

#define BUFFERLEN 40

typedef struct{           /* struct to hold elements like: 3x4 */
    int coefficient;
    char var;
    int exponent;
} term_t;

typedef struct node {
  term_t * term;            /* pointer to term */
  struct node * next_node;  /* pointer to next node */
} node_t;

#endif
```

makefile:

```
CC=gcc 
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -Wall -pedantic 

all: project1.c buildlinklist.o printandcombine.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) project1.c buildlinklist.o printandcombine.o -o project1

buildlinklist.o: buildlinklist.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c buildlinklist.c

printandcombine.o: printandcombine.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c printandcombine.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ project1.exe
```

Comment: Adding `-ggdb` to your CFLAGS will cause the program to have extra information for the debugger `gdb` to understand. It should be able to show you a line number, and also print out the values of variables. I guess by default it just showed you the function name

Comment: Without `terms.txt`, your problem isn't reproducible. Also, in `term_to_string` you `free` the string and then return it (i.e. return a _dangling_ pointer). Don't do that.

Comment: Why use recursion to traverse a linked-list??!! That's where I stopped reading this code...

Comment: Echoing user253751's response: compile with -ggdb and run your code through gdb.  You should read the man page on gdb and learn to use it.  It makes debugging a lot easier.  If you use emacs as an editor, you can run gdb from inside emacs (M-x gudgdb) and it's even easier to use.

Comment: @OneGuyHacking I think they already figured out to use gdb, but because the debugging information wasn't stored in the program, gdb was only able to tell them the function name, not the line number.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I apologize, but I am pretty new to programming, and brand new to C. What would you recommend as an alternative for traversing a linked-list?

Comment: `while( curr ) { print( curr->data ); curr = curr->next; }` <== That's a "rough cut". (PS: Don't apologise... Just look at examples in the text book, and think about the simplest way to achieve your objective.)